# Static social buttons in footer to float in the middle of page CSS?

Tags: html, css

I generated social buttons and pasted the code in html inside Body:

```
<body>
<div class="shareaholic-canvas" data-app="follow_buttons" data-app-id="28043174"></div>
</body>
```

The problem is that the buttons remain static at the bottom-right inside the footer: http://builder.ferozo.com/1589630/#!/-home/

I want them floating in the middle-right all the time like this sample: https://www.robertlandscapes.com/.

I've tried in CSS the property align div to the middle vertically but it hasn't been possible since the buttons stay only in the footer or move into the header when I try with other properties like display.

HTML

```
<div class="shareaholic-canvas"
data-app="follow_buttons"
data-app-id="28043174">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shareaholic-canvas {

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
.shareaholic-canvas{
     position: fixed; // this holds the position at all times
     right: 0;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is to use the position attribute. Like in your example, the social buttons are fixed on the right (middle) side of the website.

Try this:

```
body {
      position: relative;
}
.shareaholic-canvas {
      position: fixed;
      top: calc(50%);
      z-index: 100;
      right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, add this to the `.btn-toolbar` class.

```
.btn-toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: That is an excellent and useful solution for future needs for moving those gray share social buttons in the footer to the middle of the page. I was referring to the black follow buttons that were static in the bottom-right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add following styling inside class .btn-toolbar

```
.btn-toolbar{
background-color: #00704afa;
    position: fixed;
    right: -145px;
    top: 25%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

width and height and background change accordingly you

Comment: That is an excellent and useful solution for future needs for moving those gray share social buttons in the footer to the middle of the page. I was referring to the black follow buttons that were static in the bottom-right. Thanks

Comment: most welcome and if you satisfied with my answer to please vote it up so it makes others easy to find the right ans for the same .

Answer (score 1):

This is a more complete demonstration including button (link) containers along with their hover transitions and brand colors.

[image]

```css
body {
  min-height: 10000px;
  background-image: url(https://www.robertlandscapes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/slider-BG-5-2.jpg?x48514);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.shareaholic-canvas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shareaholic-canvas > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 42px;
  right: -10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s transform;
}

.shareaholic-canvas > a:hover,
.shareaholic-canvas > a:focus {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.youtube { background-color: #e02a20; }

.twitter { background-color: #4da7de; }

.facebook { background-color: #3e5b98; }

.instagram { background-color: #9c7c6e; }
```

```html
<div class="shareaholic-canvas">
  <a class="youtube" href="#"></a>
  <a class="twitter" href="#"></a>
  <a class="facebook" href="#"></a>
  <a class="instagram" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngzwpeqx/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that doesn't differ much from the others.. But with this snipped you can position your elements in the exact center of the window, with less code.

```
.shareaholic-canvas {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 72.5px);
}
```